# getting key of object property that references a value

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an object that looks like this:

```
var SomeObject = {

   '6.2013' : SomeArray1,
   '7.2013' : SomeArray2,
   '8.2013' : SomeArray3,
   '9.2013' : SomeArray4
};
```

Then, somewhere in my code, I have a global variable that I set like this:

```
CurrentObject = SomeObject['7.2013'];
```

Now somewhere else in my code, I need to know the key that `CurrentObject` is pointing to. Basically, I need to do this:

```
var SomeObjectKey = .....(CurrentObject);
```

and that be the string `'7.2013'`.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple cross browser way would be to iterate :

```
var SomeObject = {
    '6.2013' : 'SomeArray1',
    '7.2013' : 'SomeArray2',
    '8.2013' : 'SomeArray3',
    '9.2013' : 'SomeArray4'
};

var CurrentObject = SomeObject['7.2013'],
    SomeObjectKey;

for (key in SomeObject) {
    if (SomeObject[key] == CurrentObject) SomeObjectKey = key;
}

console.log(SomeObjectKey); // returns 7.2013
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ks6ht/)

Comment: as the other answer notes - there might be more than one key for the CurrentObject

Comment: @OlegMikheev in which case the OP should specified that possibility in the question.  That he hasn't suggests that the values in the object are unique.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I need this to work in IE8 (at least I don't have to worry about IE7:)

Comment: @frenchie: at least, add `var` before `key` and `hasOwnProperty` to the loop body.

Comment: @thg435 - probably a good idea, but as the loop only compares values, using `hasOwnProperty` isn't neccessary as undefined won't be an issue, and if the loop is in the global scope using the `var` keyword doesn't matter either, as the `for` loop doesn't have a scope of it's own.

Answer (score 2):

```
found = Object.keys(SomeObject).filter(function(key) { 
   return SomeObject[key] === CurrentObject
})
```

returns a list of keys that "point" to the value (there can be multiple ones).

As pointed out in the comments, that doesn't work in IE8 and also in Netscape navigator, Mosaic 1.2.3 and probably Lynx for DOS as well, in case anyone gives a ...

If you desperately need to support outdated engines, don't cripple your code, keep it modern, nice and clean and use shims to patch the broken parts.

Comment: you can't shim every little thing IE doesn't have, or do you use some library

Answer (score 1):

There's no "standard" call to do this, you would have to iterate over all keys of the object until you find one whose value matches the desired value.

Note that if your values are "object type" (i.e. including arrays) then a straight `===` (or `==`) test will only compare for reference equality (i.e. that the two arrays are actually the exact same two arrays) and not that their *contents* are equal.

Based somewhat on thg435's answer, you could add this functionality:

```
Object.keysFor(obj, value) = function() {
    return Object.keys(obj).filter(function(key) {
        return obj[key] === value;
    }
}
```

with usage:

```
var SomeObjectKey = Object.keysFor(SomeObject, CurrentObject);
```

For older browsers, shims for `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.filter` are available at the MDN website.

Comment: for objects, `==` and `===` do the same thing.

Comment: @thg435 I wasn't referring specifically to `===` vs `==`